# Return rowcount as 0 for rows not occuring in table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have this table:

```
MonthList (month_name, ticket)
```

I would like to get number of times a particular month occurs.

For eg in Q2, I run the following query:

```
SELECT month_name as 'Month', count('Month') as 'Ticket Count' from Monthlist
where month_name in ('May', 'June', 'July') 
group by Month order by Month asc
```

Now if there are no rows with May, May is not returned in the result at all and I get something like this:

> June 5
>
> July 10

I would like above list to also include `May 0`.

Comment: Can I assume your MonthList tables 'ticket' column is the ID of a ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you would be better off performing a join between a month table (which contains the month names) and the ticket table (which contains the tickets).

A month would have an integer ID, and the tickets table would have a column links to the months table.

You would then perform an SQL query such as this.

```
SELECT
    months.month_name AS 'Month',
    count(tickets.id) AS 'Ticket Count'
FROM
    months
LEFT JOIN
    tickets
ON
    tickets.month_id = months.id
GROUP BY
    months.id
```

This reduces the amount of data you're reproducing in the tickets table, and is a lot more flexible.

The query above is un-tested, but I'm pretty sure that should do the job, so long as your database has the required tables, of course.

Second example using month names, and filtering by specific months.

```
SELECT
    months.month_name AS 'Month',
    count(tickets.id) AS 'Ticket Count'
FROM
    months
LEFT JOIN
    tickets
ON
    tickets.month_name = months.month_name
WHERE
    months.month_name IN ("May","June","July")
GROUP BY
    months.month_name
ORDER BY
    months.month_name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! but say i had a table of only 1 column whose values were different month names, and I wanted to find out frequencies of (jan, Feb, March) how would i do it? Supposing March doesn't occur in the list, can I get something like:
Jan 2
Feb 10
March 0 ?

Comment: That's the reason for the numeric ID per month name, and a linking column on the tickets table. A left join will join between the tables, and the group/count will group by the joined months ID, resulting in 0 if there are no tickets associated with that month.

Comment: ..saying that, you could join by text month names, there's no reason why not apart from efficiency. Simply swap out the month id in the join for the month name column, so long as your months table contains all of the months. You can always provide a WHERE clause after the join to filter by specific month names. I'll add a second example query to demonstrate this.